# Calling a model method from a unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, devise

I'm adding unit tests for my models and have problems getting on track with a test for the Users model provided by `gem 'devise'`. This is my test code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should not save user without name" do    
    user = User.new

    user.email = "david@test.com"
    user.password = "david123"

    assert !user.save, "Saved user without name"
  end
end
```

When running the test with `ruby -Itest test/unit/user_test.rb` I get the following error:

```
  1) Error:
test_should_not_save_user_without_email(UserTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "password" of relation "users"  does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "password", "created_a...
                                          ^
: INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "password", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('David', 'david@test.com', 'david123', '2012-11-25 17:43:02', '2012-11-25 17:43:02', 127326141)
```

Obviously the password method that is provided by devise is not called. What is the correct way to get this test running?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that the problem is not the test code, but that I had set a value for `password`in the fixtures for users.